# How much memory will be required to place of 100 thousand elements of string type in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Conventionally, there is an array of 100 thousand elements of string type. Each cell of the array contains a string of 100 thousand characters of UTF-8 encoding. How much memory will be required to place such an array in computer memory? Is it even possible to place such an array in memory? Are there any restrictions on storing this amount of data?

I'm just trying to figure out if this is possible and how much memory it takes. I tried to create a large array of strings. But I don't understand how much memory was occupied.

Comment: You can figure this out, can't you?  There is a certain amount of overhead for each string object, but 100k strings of length 100k will take up 10 gigabytes of memory.  So, Find Another Way.

Comment: As far as I know the JVM stores strings using UTF16 so it would be double that size, traditionally using a database was the go-to solution for storing large volumes of data, I don't think you need to re-invent anything here

Comment: Note since Java 9, the `String` class will only use 1 byte per character if they are all Latin-1, and only use 2 bytes per character if needed.